# Como enviar datos de dos formularios en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Lo que quiero hacer es que tengo dos formularios y enviar los datos ami base de datos ... me guardan los datos los dos formularios si en mi controlador borro losdatos a enviar pero si pongo los dos datos no me enviar me sale error
no se si me explico bien pero este es mi codigo del form y de mi controlador y mi routes.. Lo que quiero es que si uso un formulario me envie los datos y si uso el otro me envie sus datos (ambos tiene tablas diferentes).. no se si me explique bien.. espero me puedan ayduar... de antemanos gracias...!
Mi route es

```
 Gracias ya lo solucione..!
```

Comment: Buenas, si son dos formularios diferentes creo que tendrías que usar dos operaciones diferentes en el controlador, una para cada formulario a gestionar. Como no está el código completo no te puedo dar más pistas. Un saludo.

Comment: @XMP En mi controlador ese es todo el codigo que tengo en mi routes tambien ese es todo el codigo que tengo pero el formulario que puse es el primero ahi ya puse el segundo formulario con eso seria todo el codigo que estoy usando .. si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradeceria mucho..!